# Intel XDK Cordova and Crosswalk issues

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, crosswalk

I made an app with crosswalk optimization. I tried to build my app without the cloud based cordova system. So I followed these steps (indicated in the tutorial):

1- Generate a Package (zip), with all plugins needed. (crosswalk 19 (embeded), minimum android api 14, target android api 21)

2- Created a cordova project (cordova --version ==> 7.0.1)

3- Added android platform

4- Cordova build andoroid.

But, the build fails. It's give me an error when generates Java code form Crosswalk Web Engine. This is the error:

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\MyApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:55: error: XWalkWebViewEngine is not abstract and does not override abstract method evaluateJavascript(String,ValueCallback) in CordovaWebViewEngine
public class XWalkWebViewEngine implements CordovaWebViewEngine {
       ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:  -Xmx512M

I dont understand way this error, maybe versions issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. The problem was because I have to update crosswalk plugin to 2.2.0 (cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.2.0)